# Full Asset URL in a Rails .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a bookmarklet that can be loaded on any website.

It works like this;

- loads `http://my.example.com/assets/bookmarklet.js`
- includes `http://my.example.com/assets/bookmarklet.css`

The css file is added to the dom via `bookmarklet.js`, so it needs to know where this is.

My code is as follows;

```
// assets/javascripts/bookmarklet.js.erb

var config = {
  stylesheetUrl: '<%= asset_path("bookmarklet.css", :only_path => false) %>'
}
```

But no matter what I try this renders as

```
var config = {
  stylesheetUrl: '/assets/bookmarklet.css'
}
```

I need the `asset_path` to return a full url.
But `asset_url` doesn't exist, and I can't find an option to `asset_path` that will prepend the current domain.

Any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set an explicit asset host for each environment. For example:

```
# development.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

Comment: Does this require the `only_path` parameter to `asset_path`?

Comment: @collindo Not that I'm aware of - I don't recall using it.

Comment: doesn't seem to be a complete solution for rails 4