# How do I construct an absolute URL in a js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a js.erb file in my Rails app that will be included as an *external script* by another site. I would like to define a variable that stores the absolute URL of the Rails asset path (protocol + host + asset prefix) such that the URLs look something like this:

Dev

```
var absURL = "http://localhost:3000/assets/";
```

Staging

```
var absURL = "http://staging.foo.com/assets/";
```

Prod

```
var absURL = "http://foo.com/assets/";
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this—the `request` object isn't available here and the asset path helpers are only returning paths relative to the root.

Some suggestions have been to pass the URL to the script or render the JS on an endpoint so that the `root_url` is available. Ideally, there is a solution for the above, but I'm open to other ideas.

**Edit:** I did see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186523/full-asset-url-in-a-rails-js-erb-file). I'm basically attempting the same thing however, I would like to avoid adding specific environment variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that I understand your question, I'll answer according....

First option:

Edit your files:

- config/environments/development.rb
- config/environments/test.rb
- config/environments/production.rb

and you have to write the host like:

default_url_options[:host] = 'www.example.com'

then you can create a javascript within your assets like **app/assets/javascript/test.js.erb**, make sure to add the .erb extension so ruby code is executed first when compiling the javascript and add the code:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>
var absURL = '<%= root_url %>';
```

Have in mind that because its an asset, it will be precompile when deploying once, and the minified version will be served for every request (so the ruby code will be executed just when deploying).

---

Option 2:

you can add a route of your choice in **config/routes.rb** like:

```
match 'my_js', to: 'home#my_js'
```

and then you can create a view in your home controller: **app/views/home/my_js.js.rb** and add the ruby code right there:

```
var absURL = '<%= root_url %>';
```

Be sure to include the [actionpack-page_caching gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) in order to generate a cache for your action, so it gets compiled on first request and then it will just serve the compiled version on all the other requests (although it won't minify the javascript, so the assets may be a better solution)

Comment: I think you're right. I think these are my only options aside from hard-coding them into the file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable in your view before including the javascript file:

```
<%= javascript_tag("var absURL = '#{root_url}';") %>
```

Then on your javascript file, you will have the variable absURL, you can check by trying on your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(absURL);
});
```

Comment: `root_path` just gives me `/`.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I'm currently operating under the assumption that the site that will include this JS will not be passing the URL to the script.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to put root_url :) Can you update the question with a use case? I mean, a third party website will include your javascript file? Your website will include a third party javascript file?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for asking for clarification. Hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

First in your view set `hostURL` variable

```
#application.html.erb
<script>
   window.hostURL = "<%=j request.original_url %>";
</script>
```

And now you can use hostURL variable inside a javascript file but before using the variable make sure DOM is loaded

```
#script.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var absURL = host_url + 'assets/';
  alert(absURL);
})
```

I hope this helps

## Edit

Also take a look at gon gem https://github.com/gazay/gon , you might find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. This will probably work as an alternative if I can't find a way to make it available directly in the JS file.